# How to tell if Mono actually uses LLVM?

Tags: mono, llvm

Starting from version 5.14, Mono apparently enables use of LLVM by default (that's what `mono --version` tells me).
I also have installed the package `llvm` and I would like to know **if there is a way to tell if Mono actually uses LLVM instead of its builtin JIT**.

Actually I was thinking of two ways to detect this:

- Using something in command line.
- Using some code directly from a Mono application.

**Edit 2018-10-12**: Fun fact, starting from version 5.16, LLVM is not supported anymore.

Comment: [ldd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) lists the shared libraries, which might or might not list an LLVM-related library.

Comment: @arnt : the LLVM choice is made at runtime (either using a command line parameter or an environment variable), so basically, outside the application execution there is no difference at all. Nice try anyway ;)

Comment: Where do you get the information about LLVM not being supported anymore? There is nothing like that in the release notes: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.16.0/

Comment: @dzan the version I tested simply didn't run LLVM, event when asked for. And the diagnostic written below told me the same thing: LLVM is not used. Maybe this has changed since, I didn't retry.

Comment: Mono supports LLVM from 5.18 out of the box, https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/mono-llvm/

Answer (score 0):

I came to a solution. However it seems that currently Mono is very unstable on LLVM, so the C# code below is theoric (I could only check it without LLVM).

## The idea

Thanks to arnt who gave me the idea to check mapped libraries.
The LLVM is loaded if the `mono` runtime opens a library named `libmono-llvm.so`.
From this, we can deduce a bash way and a C# to detect whether we're using LLVM or not.

**Caution**: this works only on Linux (because it uses the procfs)

## Using bash

Given `mono` pid as `$1` parameter, the following command returns `1` if LLVM is used, `0` otherwise.

```sh
find /proc/$1/map_files/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls | grep libmono-llvm.so | head -1 | wc -l
```

## At runtime in C#

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Mono.Unix;

public static class LlvmInformation
{
    private static bool? _isLlvmEnabled;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether Mono uses LLVM.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if this instance is LLVM enabled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public static bool IsLlvmEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_isLlvmEnabled.HasValue)
                _isLlvmEnabled = LoadLlvmEnabled();
            return _isLlvmEnabled.Value;
        }
    }

    private static bool LoadLlvmEnabled()
    {
        var pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        var mapFilesDirectory = $"/proc/{pid}/map_files";
        var mapFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(mapFilesDirectory);
        foreach (var mapFile in mapFiles)
        {
            var symbolicLinkInfo = new UnixSymbolicLinkInfo(mapFile);
            if (symbolicLinkInfo.FileType == FileTypes.SymbolicLink
                && symbolicLinkInfo.GetContents().Name.Contains("libmono-llvm.so"))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Good luck with this!